# Issue in running system commands from python script continuously?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a python script that checks continuously for snmpd and a socket script to be running .If any of these get killed it should kill both and start new session. The problem 
is once socket is running it wait for connection for long ,in between if anyone kill  snmpd  its not getting started (think its not going to loop back).What may be the reason and a possible solution.? any optimisation possible for the code?

```
def terminator():
    i=0
    j=0
    os.system("ps -eaf|grep snmpd|cut -d \" \" -f7 >snmpd_pid.txt")
    os.system("ps -eaf|grep iperf|cut -d \" \" -f7 >iperf_pid.txt")
    os.system("ps -eaf|grep sock_bg.py|cut -d \" \" -f7 >script_pid.txt")
    snmpd_pids = tuple(line.strip() for line in open('snmpd_pid.txt'))
    iperf_pids = tuple(line.strip() for line in open('iperf_pid.txt'))
    script_pids = tuple(line.strip() for line in open('script_pid.txt'))
    k1 = len(snmpd_pids) - 2
    k2 = len(iperf_pids) - 2
    k3 = len(script_pids) - 2
    if (k1 == 0 or k3 == 0):
        for i in range(k1):
            cmd = 'kill -9 %s' %(snmpd_pids[i])
            os.system(cmd)
        for i in range(k2):
            cmd = 'kill -9 %s' %(iperf_pids[i])
            os.system(cmd)
        for i in range(k3):
            cmd = 'kill -9 %s' %(script_pids[i])
            os.system(cmd)
    os.system("/usr/local/sbin/snmpd -f -L -d -p 9999")
    os.system("python /home/maxuser/utils/python-bg/sock_bg.py")
try:
    terminator()
except:
    print 'an exception occured'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer ,its the problem of getting the prompt back .
I used screen -d -m  option and now able to get intended result.

```
os.system("screen -d -m /usr/local/sbin/snmpd -f -L -d -p 9999 &")
os.system("screen -d -m python /home/maxuser/utils/python-bg/sock_bg.py &")
```

Also those system commands need to be inside if condition.